# AngularJS returning a promise from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use the following code to get my AngularJS app token from my client API, then I save this token in a cookie that expires every 30 minutes. I've added code to check first on the cookie if it is not expired then I can use the token in the cookie, if expired then I will request a new token from the server.

Problem I am facing now is that getToken must return a promise, which is easy if I am calling the API using $http, but wondering how I can return a promise after checking on the cookie and return the token from the cookie without calling the API? Any example is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
  getToken : function(){
      var token = '';
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var urlString = 'http://domainname.com/client.php';

      //returns '' if cookie expired or token if cookie exist...
      token = LocalService.getTokenCookie();

     if(token == ''){
      $http({ method:'POST',
            url: urlString,
            headers: { 'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
            responseType: 'json'
       }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            deferred.resolve(data);
            token = data.Token;
            //....save token in a cookie...          
      }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
            deferred.reject(status);
      });           
      }
      return deferred.promise;   
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can immediatelly resolve the deferred and `promise.then(...)` will still be handled correclty (even if called after resolving). E.g.:

```
getToken : function(){
    var token = '';
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    ...
    token = LocalService.getTokenCookie();

    if(token == ''){
        $http({...}).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            ...
        }).error(function (data, status) { 
            deferred.reject(status);
        });
    } else {
        /* Resolve immediatelly */
        deferred.resolve(token);
    }

    return deferred.promise;   
}
```